# How to retrieve ALL pages from PDF as a single string in Python 3 using PyPDF2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf, pdf-extraction

In order to get a single string from a multi-paged PDF I'm doing this:

```
import PyPDF2
pdfFileObject = open('sample.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObject)
count = pdfReader.numPages
for i in range(count):
    page = pdfReader.getPage(i)
    output = page.extractText()
output
```

The result is a string from a **single page** (the last page in the document) - just as it should be according to the [PyPDF2 documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileReader.html). I applied this method because I've read some people suggesting it to read whole PDF, what does not work in my case.

Obviously, this is a basic operation, and I apologize in advance for my lack of experience. I tried other solutions like Tika, PDFMiner and Textract, but PyPDF seems to be the only one letting me so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update:

As suggested, I defined an `output` as a list and then appended to it (as I thought) all pages in a loop like this:

```
for i in range(count):
    page = pdfReader.getPage(i)
    output = []
    output.append(page.extractText())
```

The result, thought, is a single string in the list like `['sample content from the last page of PDF']`

Comment: Aren't you overwriting `output` every time?

Comment: @AMC I guess... But it's impossible to `concat str to bytes`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that relates to my question, sorry.

Comment: @AMC If I use 
`output += page.extractText()`
to avoid overwriting, as suggested below, I get
`TypeError: can't concat str to bytes`

Comment: How do you define `output`? In any case, what I had in mind was using something like a list.

Comment: @AMC As a string. Sorry, I don't quite understand. You mean to get an output as a list of strings retrieved from each page? How to get such a list if `getPage` takes a single page number as an argument?

Comment: _As a string._ Then that explains the error, right? _Sorry, I don't quite understand. You mean to get an output as a list of strings retrieved from each page? How to get such a list if getPage takes a single page number as an argument?_ All I meant is that could define `output` as a list and then append the result of `page.extractText()` where you're currently assigning it to `output`.

Comment: @AMC Thank you, but it creates list with a single string like `['sample content from the last page of PDF']`. How can I loop over the whole range of pages? I posted that piece of code in the question update.

Comment: Look at where you defined the list, it’s a similar issue to the first one.

Comment: Do you want me to post an answer?

Comment: @AMC Sure! Certainly I'm not the only beginner who does not know how to loop properly =)

Comment: Done! Let me know if you want me to expand on any area.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be because of this line:

```
output = page.extractText()
```

Try this instead:

```
output += page.extractText()
```

Because in your code, you're overwriting the value of the "output" variable instead of appending to it. Don't forget to declare the "output" variable before the for loop. So `output = ''` before `for i in range(count):`

Comment: Thank you! Apparently, yes.
`TypeError: can't concat str to bytes`
This is an error I get. As I understand, this is because I take 'rb' as an argument for 'open'. But then 
`PdfFileReader stream/file object is not in binary mode`
Is there an option to convert bytes to string some other way?

Comment: What are you trying to do? 

To write the output to a text file:
with open('sample.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(output)

Don't forget to declare the "output" variable before the for loop. So output = '' before for i in range(count):

Answer (score 4):

This code works:

```
import os, glob, PyPDF2, sys

file_path = 'C:/Users/ipeter/Desktop/Webdriverdownloads'
read_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(file_path,'*.pdf'))

for files in read_files:
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(files)
    count = pdfReader.numPages
    output = []
    for i in range(count):
        page = pdfReader.getPage(i)
        output.append(page.extractText())
    print(output)
```

The first loop reads all files in a folder. The second loop reads all pages in the pdf.

```
output[0] = pdfpage1
output[1] = pdfpage2
output[2] = pdfpage3
```

...
etc

If you need entire pdf in one string you can save `newoutput` use join function:

```
seperator = ','
newoutput = seperator.join(output)
```

or simplify:

```
newoutput = ','.join(output)
```

Comment: @Gavrk Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

You're overwriting the `output` variable each time.

While you could concatenate the bytes together using `output +=`, it's probably safer to use a list instead, in which case you would have `output = []` defined outside the loop, and replace `output = page.extractText()` with `output.append(page.extractTest())`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create output as empty string first..

```
output = ""
for i in range(pdfReader.numPages):
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)
    output += pageObj.extractText()
```